# Merging 2 panda dataframes while keeping all columns

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to merge 2 panda dataframes. They look like

DF1

```
col1        col2          col3           col4           col5
A            SAT           MON            5               3
B            MON           FRI            -1              2
C            FRI           TUE            8               4
D            TUE           WED            2               4
```

DF2

```
col1        col2          col3           col4           col5
A            SAT           MON            5               3
B            MON           FRI            -1              2
C            WED           THUR           8               4
D            THUR          SAT            2               4
```

Wanted Result

```
col1        col2          col3           col4           col5        col1_2          col2_2        col3_2          col4_2        col5_2                
A            SAT           MON            5               3           A            SAT           MON            5               3
B            MON           FRI            -1              2           B            MON           FRI            -1              2
C            FRI           TUE            8               4
D            TUE           WED            2               4
                                                                      C            WED           THUR           8               4
                                                                      D            THUR          SAT            2               4
```

I used `merged_df = df1.merge(df2, on=['col1','col2','col3'], how='outer')` but it gives me the below result which is what I expected, but dont want. I want something like the above result. Is there anyway to get my expected result?

Result

```
col1        col2          col3           col4           col5
A            SAT           MON            5               3
B            MON           FRI            -1              2
C            FRI           TUE            8               4
D            TUE           WED            2               4
C            WED           THUR           8               4
D            THUR          SAT            2               4
```

Answer (score 1):

Try with `combine_first`

```
l=['col1','col2','col3']
df = df1.set_index(l).combine_first(df2.set_index(l)).reset_index()
df
Out[28]: 
  col1  col2  col3  col4  col5
0    A   SAT   MON   5.0   3.0
1    B   MON   FRI  -1.0   2.0
2    C   FRI   TUE   8.0   4.0
3    C   WED  THUR   8.0   4.0
4    D  THUR   SAT   2.0   4.0
5    D   TUE   WED   2.0   4.0
```

Comment: This does not produce the wanted result from my post. Could you take another look?

Comment: @new_programmer_22n you mean the order ?

Comment: I apologize I realize I did not copy in the correct wanted result. I have updated it now